# SWF file only plays an abbreviated version when not accessed through an internet connection on Safari- How can this version be saved for offline use?

Tags: firefox, flash, safari, swf

I have a young niece who has gotten hooked on online flash games but has no internet connection at home. I've been trying to save them on a hard drive for her to access offline, and so far have been successful using a mozilla plugin and an offline flash player. However, one particular game only plays in its full version on safari. I've tried everything to download the file from safari-plugins, archiving the entire page, even going through the source code- and while it saves like every other file from this particular site, once the internet connection is cut it goes back to the same shortened, partially-functional version seen when accessed through firefox. Is there any explanation for why the file itself would play differently- maybe another file that needs to be saved with it? And, more importantly, is there any way I can preserve the full version of the game even when offline? It's not a matter of life or death, obviously, but it's got me pretty seriously stumped.

Here's the link to the page:

http://www.dolldivine.com/rebel-girl-dress-up.php

Answer (score 0):

stick with firefox and download the addon "userAgentSwitcher" for its maturity and stability.
Use the menus to emulate Safari

Revisit the site and verify it can access the content in the manner you like.

Then get the addon YoutubeDownload, open its menus and enable the "save SWF files for FlashGames" or similar option since there wil be only one like it.

revisit the site and have her finsih the game as she likes or until she turns old enough to discover  boys.
Open YT downloader and you'll find a list of files ready to download, select your location and do so accordingly.

Flash content, espeically interactive flash content like games is often segmented into multiple files to reduce the amount of time you spend caching content for play, most flash legacy flash content except for streaming YT videos but swf game files like you're leeching (leech is a generic term like "junk bond" and not a characterization) is often segmented at milestones like book chapters and explains why your prior attempts to access offline didn't succeed.